# R Shiny leaflet - draw animated line from one coordinate straight to another

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I have a dataset of geographic coordinates (lag & long) with timestamp, tracking the location of a moving object. I'm trying to make animated path out it such that:

1. Location 1 is marked with a circle/marker
2. From location 1 to location 2: A path (just straingt line, no need for google map navigation fancy sutff) extends out gradually with a speed caculated using the distance between two locations and timestamp difference.
3. Location 2 is marked.
4. From location 2 to location 3:...

...repeat until the last location.

I have no trouble iterating over the sorted dataset, drawing marks with `addCircleMarkers()`, and calculating the speed/distance/travel-time from one coordinate to another. However, at the moment, I can only draw the path *immediately instead of with moving animation* using `addPolyline()`.

How can I let the path extends from initial location and gradually move to next with an adjustable pace?

Edit: the code I have so far is below

```
observe({
    if(startAnimation()) {
      
      if (i() <= nrow(cat_data)) {
        leafletProxy("map") %>%
          addCircleMarkers(
            lng = cat_data$location.long[i()], 
            lat = cat_data$location.lat[i()], 
            color = "yellow",
            group = "track",
            popup = paste("Timestamp:", cat_data$timestamp[i()])
          )
        
        if (i() > 1) {
          leafletProxy("map") %>%
            addPolylines(
              lng = c(cat_data$location.long[i()-1], cat_data$location.long[i()]), 
              lat = c(cat_data$location.lat[i()-1], cat_data$location.lat[i()]), 
              color = "black",
              group = "track"
            )
        }
        
        i(i() + 1)  

      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Can you share what you've written so far?

Comment: Thanks. I tried a few things but I don't think it's possible using existing R packages. For one thing, when you use `observe` nothing is updated until the whole block has been executed. What I did find though was this javascript add on which seems to do what you want: https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim and it should be possible to incorporate: https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92

Comment: @smartse Thank you very much for taking time to help!! I'm trying to work around this

Comment: `{madpeck}` has an `add_animated_line()` function that should do what you want. It's similar to the [`animated_arc`](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/layers.html#animated-arcs), but I haven't written the article for it. It also has an `add_trips()` if you _do_ want a 'fancy stuff'.